# Accessing MySQL database to add markers on Google Maps API V3 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently developing an Android Application that has Google Maps integrated into it.

I decided to use webview and Google Maps API v3 because I want to configure the map and delete the Points of Interest from it. I also chose to use it because I want to limit the zoom and panning capabilities of the map.
I have successfully done these things.

Now, I want to ask anyone if it is possible to add markers to the map using the data from my MYSQL database. My database contains the following:

1. The name of the place
2. The Longitude and Latitude values
3. And a brief description of the place

I've read a question here that says how to display an info window when a marker is tapped, but I am wondering if it is possible to direct a user to a link when an infowindow is tapped.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in the title:
To display markers from MySQL, see this article from the [articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/):
[Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

[link to Wayback Machine version of page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160426225702/https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

The second question

> I am wondering if it is possible to direct a user to a link when an infowindow is tapped.

If you put a link in an infowindow, it will work.  If you are having problems with that post the code or a link to your map that exhibits the problem.