# Add markers from rails database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a map with Google Maps API to reference restaurants based on their location. Each restaurant in my database (sqlite3) has a title, a description and two coordinates (latitude, longitude). I can successfully create entries in my database but struggle to find a solution to call in JS each restaurant's coordinates from the database.

Different solutions have been proposed on Stackoverflow of which [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104209/cluster-markers-with-google-maps-api-locations-from-database), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503254/accessing-mysql-database-to-add-markers-on-google-maps-api-v3-using-javascript) and a [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677741/how-to-add-locationsmarkers-on-a-google-map-from-database), but none of the answers my question as I'm working exclusively with JS and Ruby (on rails).

Would you have suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could try is by using json. For example in the controller.

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @restaurant}
    end

  end
end
```

Then the restaurant can be accessed in javascript (I'll use JQuery)

```
 $.getJSON("show_page_url.json", function(data){
   //data will contain the @restaurant object 
   //so data.latitute should return the value
}
```

Maybe this helps. I used it for a simple project I did recently, but maybe there are better methods.

Comment: Instead of "show_page_url.json" I would have something like "1.json" (1 being the page id). What would you recommend to display only the marker corresponding to the page id ? 

I was thinking of something like this (say you have 2 pages): for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) { $.getJSON(i + '&format=json', function(data) { $.each(data, function(key, value) { alert(data.latitude) [...]  }); });

But instead of i, there should be a condition that only displays the latitude/longitude corresponding to the page id...

Comment: Try using window.location.href to get the current URL maybe? Think that's what I did. Then it will only get the data matching the ID in the url.

Comment: $.getJSON(window.location.href +'.json', function(data){//do whatever here}

Comment: thanks, I used a slightly different method : var markerId = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')); $.getJSON(markerId + '&format=json', function(data) { ..... }

Comment: Cool. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to read [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) from Goolge Maps Javascript API and play with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
   #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here, you need to

- create your own `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
- create `div` with id;
- connect Google's javascript, which when will load, will load also js-function `initMap()`
- define `initMap`-function with map and marker settings.

**Next step: getting data from database and passing to JavaScript**.

I used [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) for transferring data from backend to frontend:

in controller:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def root
  gon.locations = Location.all
end
```

in layout:

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<head>
<%= include_gon %>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
```

in view:

```
<!-- app/views/application/root.html.erb -->
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: { lat: gon.locations[0].lat, lng: gon.locations[0].lng }
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < gon.locations.length; i++){
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: gon.locations[i].lat, lng: gon.locations[i].lng },
        title: gon.locations[i].name,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }
<script>
```

But, if you don't want use [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) for passing data from backend to frontend, you can do this by plain rails:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def root
  @json_data = {
    locations: {
      # ...
    },
    # ...
  }.to_json
end

<!-- views/posts/edit.html.erb -->
<script>
  var json_data = JSON.parse('<%= raw(escape_javascript(@json_data)) %>');
</script>
```

**Also, I created [rails demo application](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q45118406-add-markers-from-rails-database), you can play with it.**

- [This commit](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q45118406-add-markers-from-rails-database/commit/09e6d545e672f8fc5395d4ac533eb7cf4a973799) doing all job, to write 'ICE' word by markers on Antarctica. [image]
- See these files for more details:

  - `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`
  - `app/views/application/root.html.erb`
  - `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
- I used [this online service](http://www.geoplaner.com/) to create coordinates for 'ICE' word

Comment: thanks Alex, your demo application helped me passing data from back to front. Based on your method, would you have an idea about how to display the Google Map on the right side of the window and the restaurants database on the left side ? So that each time a restaurant  is selected (each restaurant has a unique id), the corresponding marker appears on the map without opening a new page ?

Comment: In my [demo](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q45118406-add-markers-from-rails-database/blob/master/app/views/application/root.html.erb#L8) I use `center` option to position map viewport by specifying marker's coordinates.  
  
**About list** - you can add `onclick` event handlers to each RestaurantItem (let it be the `ul > li` for example). In `onclick` handler you will change map settings. Think it will works.

Answer (score 1):

To make variables in your rails app accessible for js code, you need to save these values in rendered html and later your js code can take values from html. You can use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) so you don't have to write the solution yourself. Here are the steps to get it working:

1. install the gem 'gon'.
2. add `<%= Gon::Base.render_data %>` to your layout.
3. set variable: `gon.push(restaurants: restaurants)`.
4. in your js code, read data and pass it to your map.